# Create button click function not working in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Hi guys i have a table  where i have a add new project link ...when i click on that it takes me to a create page where i have textboxes for inserting new record and a button to create..but i click on create button its not working can any one help me where am i doing wrong here is my code

This is my create.aspx page:

```
             <%: ViewBag.Title="Create" %>

         <fieldset>
       <legend>Projects</legend>

  <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.projectName)%>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
       <%:Html.EditorFor(model => model.projectName)%>
      <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.projectName)%>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
       <%:Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)%>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
       <%:Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)%>
       <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)%>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
    <%:Html.LabelFor(model=>model.status) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    <%:Html.EditorFor(model=>model.status) %>
    <%:Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.status) %>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
  </fieldset>
```

And this is my controller function:

```
              public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ProjectModel model)
    {
        var modelList = new List<ProjectModel>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LMIT-0039;Initial Catalog=BugTracker;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            conn.Open();                
            SqlCommand insertcommande = new SqlCommand("Sp_AddNewProject", conn);
            insertcommande.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            insertcommande.Parameters.Add("@ProjectName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.projectName;
            insertcommande.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.Description;
            insertcommande.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.status;
            insertcommande.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return View( modelList);
    }
```

when i click on create button in aspx page it should go to create method in my controller .....what am i doing wrong here.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put this in my create.aspx page BeginForm statement:

```
        <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
      <form action=”/members/Create” method=”post”></form>
```

and added

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.post)]
public ActionResult Create(ProjectModel model)
{
    var modelList = new List<ProjectModel>();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LMIT-0039;Initial Catalog=BugTracker;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        conn.Open();                
        SqlCommand insertcommande = new SqlCommand("Sp_AddNewProject", conn);
        insertcommande.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        insertcommande.Parameters.Add("@ProjectName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.projectName;
        insertcommande.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.Description;
        insertcommande.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.status;
        insertcommande.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    return View( modelList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `form` in your View. That is one problem.

Answer (score 0):

Visit MSDN for BeginForm: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410596.aspx

Comment: He's not using Razor--right idea, but it would be more beneficial to use the syntax he did.

Comment: Good spot Brian. Changed so the link points to right location.

Comment: I removed my downvote :-) That said, a good piece of advice to you is to provide answers that are more than a link (unless you're pointing someone to a duplicate question). That will increase your chance of upvotes and accepted answers. So, in this case, instead of just posting the link, it might have been beneficial to include some code. The idea is that SO can be a good source of reference and the link won't be necessary except as a reference.